# USB dongle not accessible in Linux

Tags: usb, usb-device

I have a USB dongle (security token) to connect company servers; in fact there is a private LAN with some servers in it. The company has got me a public address with this security token to connect to those servers.
When I connect the USB to the PC (running Linux Mint 17.2),
it doesn't appear as a SCSI disk (`sd`) device, as shown below:

```
# ls /dev/sd*
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda5
```

but when I use `lsusb` I can see it:

```
# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 010: ID e854:1230  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:030d Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The first ID – `e854:1230` – is it.
With the below command I also can monitor the USB:

```
# udevadm monitor --udev
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing

UDEV  [17049.330199] add      /class/usbmisc (class)
UDEV  [17049.337488] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [17049.338358] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [17049.339199] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:E854:1230.000A (hid)
UDEV  [17049.339491] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/usbmisc/hiddev0 (usbmisc)
UDEV  [17049.339991] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:E854:1230.000A/hidraw/hidraw0 (hidraw)
```

I need to mount it but I don't see it in `/dev/` to be mounted.
What have I missed?

Comment: More than likely this device doesn't operate as a block device (and I'm not sure how it would). Why do you think a security token should provide an SCSI interface (that's what the `sd` prefix means)? Why do you think that a security token should be providing a block device at all?

Comment: try doing a `dmesg -wH` (basically following dmesg) and plugging the USB stick in and see if it shows up there.